# Cosa sono le "leghe" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *Artemisia*, di Anna Banti, ho letto:

> Questo presentimento fu certezza il diciannove ottobre, durante le ultime **leghe** prima di Beaune e le rocce brulicavano di capre nere bianche e brune, persin bionde, ferme a barba levata fra gli arbusti a veder passar la vettura: come persone.

Nel brano precedente, la pittrice Artemisia Gentileschi è in viaggio in Francia.

Un po' più avanti nel libro questo vocabolo appare di nuovo:

> Quando Delfina cantava dimenticava d'essere serva d'osteria e non pensava a far nulla, le braccia le si distendevano lungo i fianchi e la sua bocca morbida dolcemente increspata di suono rimaneva semiaperta, quasi attenta a una risposta. Così la disegnò Artemisia, su un sudicio cartone, mentre di sotto strepitavano vetturali e viaggiatori e la padrona la cercava: nessuna delle due se ne accorse. Sicché la ragazza fu scacciata e l'italiana non seppe neppure che era partita all'alba, sotto la pioggia, per la sua capanna fra i boschi, a piedi per venti  **leghe**, a patir la fame.

La mia domanda è sul significato di "leghe" in questi testi. Si riferisce al gruppo di comuni ([accezione **3** nel vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/lega1/)) che si trovavano prima di Beaune nel primo brano e a quello che c'era tra l'osteria e la capanna di Delfina nel secondo?

Comment: No, in entrambi i casi si tratta della misura di lunghezza. Nel primo, serve a dare un'indicazione spaziale (ormai mancava poco a...), nel secondo serve semplicemente come misura di distanza.

Comment: *Ventimila leghe sotto i mari*, che potresti conoscere con il titolo *Vint mil llegües de viatge submarí*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La *lega* è anche una unità di misura della distanza. In italiano indica circa tre miglia (http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/lega3/).